# while enabling the omega theme live reload error

Tags: drupal, themes, livereload

I'm new to Drupal and I just started with theming. After enabling the omega theme, I'm getting this error:

> LiveReload is currently enabled but could not be loaded. Please ensure
>   that livereload.js is being served at the configured path
>   (http://localhost:35729/livereload.js?snipver=1).

What can I do avoid the error?

Comment: Guard-livereload 2.* will fail silently if the default port (35729) is taken.
so make sure the port is free.

Answer (score 1):

After looking for a solutions on Google and I found few of them and I have mentioned below under solutions.

### What is LiveReload?

*LiveReload is a tool for web developers and designers.*

To use LiveReload, you need a client (this script) in your browser and a server running on your development machine.

This repository (livereload.js) implements the client side of the protocol. The client connects to a LiveReload server via web sockets and listens for incoming change notifications. When a CSS or an image file is modified, it is live-refreshed without reloading the page. When any other file is modified, the page is reloaded.

**You should refer to your LiveReload server/app/tool's documentation, rather that this repository. You should use the copy of livereload.js script bundled with your server, because it's guaranteed to be compatible, and may be customized for that server.**

***Solutions I found***

- The message just means that livereload.js can't be loaded **LiveReload is enabled in the theme settings but not working because Guard is not running). Fix: Run Guard or disable LiveReload.**
- navigate into your theme's folder via your CLI (Terminal, et.al.) and run this command:

  $ drush omega-guard